# how to save image in database

Tags: .net, asp.net

```
FileUpload img = (FileUpload)UploadImg;
        Byte[] imgByte = null;
        if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile!=null)
        {
            HttpPostedFile File = UploadImg.PostedFile;
            imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
            File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
        }    **strong text**
```

here i want to save an image in database . so i want to convert an image to byte array. for that i wrote the above code. but here the if condition is not executed

Comment: strange, can you show your aspx ?

Comment: Unless it is absolutely critical that the images are stored in the database I would recommend to store them as normal files on the file system and store the URI to the file in the database. Storing images in the database blows up your database & in most cases does not offer much added value (I see cases for medical imagery where it could be useful). Storing the images this way also allows you to offload the image storage to a CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a file upload control on your page:

```
<asp:FileUpload id="UploadImg" runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />
```

the following should work:

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(UploadImg.HasFile)
    {
        byte[] imgByte = UploadImg.FileBytes;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(UploadImg.FileName);
        // TODO: Save the image to the database
    }
}
```

Comment: i store a bmp image.  if(UploadImg.HasFile) does not executed.but if(UploadImg.PostedFile) will be executed .but imgByte cannot store any value